# why my json_encode not work in my web but work in localhost?

Tags: php

I have the code like this, but why it won't work in web but work in localhost ?

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    include('functions.php');
    /*defined settings - start*/
    ini_set("memory_limit", "99M");
    ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
    define('IMAGE_SMALL_DIR', './uploades/small/');
    define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE', 50);
    define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR', './uploades/medium/');
    define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE', 250);
    define('IMAGE_LARGE_DIR', './foto/');
    define('IMAGE_LARGE_SIZE', 250);
    /*defined settings - end*/

    if(isset($_FILES['image_upload_file'])){
        $output['status']=FALSE;
        set_time_limit(0);
        $allowedImageType = array("image/gif",   "image/jpeg",   "image/pjpeg",   "image/png",   "image/x-png"  );

        if ($_FILES['image_upload_file']["error"] > 0) {
            $output['error']= "Error in File";
        }
        elseif (!in_array($_FILES['image_upload_file']["type"], $allowedImageType)) {
            $output['error']= "You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file";
        }
        elseif (round($_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024) > 4096) {
            $output['error']= "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
        } else {
            /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - start*/
            createDir(IMAGE_SMALL_DIR);
            createDir(IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR);
            /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - end*/
            $path[0] = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['tmp_name'];
            $file = pathinfo($_FILES['image_upload_file']['name']);
            $fileType = $file["extension"];
            $desiredExt='jpg';
            $fileNameNew = rand(333, 999) . time() . ".$desiredExt";
            $path[1] = IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR . $fileNameNew;
            $path[2] = IMAGE_SMALL_DIR . $fileNameNew;

            if (createThumb($path[0], $path[1], $fileType, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE,IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE)) {

                if (createThumb($path[1], $path[2],"$desiredExt", IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE,IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE)) {
                    $output['status']=TRUE;
                    $output['image_medium']= $path[1];
                    $output['image_small']= $path[2];
                }
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($output);

 }
?>
```

I just so tired for all of this, please help me!!!!
And I have code like this to make the image appear but it won't appear

```
 $(document).on('change', '#ifile', function () {
    var progressBar = $('.progressBar'), bar = $('.progressBar .bar'), percent = $('.progressBar .percent');

    $('#image_upload_form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            progressBar.fadeIn();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },

         success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {      
            objy = $.parseJSON(html);   
            if(objy.status){        
                    $("#img8>img").prop('src','objy.image_medium');     

            }else{
                alert(objy.error);
            }
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {


            progressBar.fadeOut();          
        }   
    }).submit();        

    });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i cannot display my image in web but i can do it in localhost

Comment: i think the problem is in json_encode,but i don't know what must i doing now

Comment: check your `json` with `var_dump`. Sometime because of character encoding it will not show values.

Comment: nothing happen.

Comment: nothing happen means? a blank json?

Comment: Open your browsers  network traffic monitor and check what the response content looks like.

Comment: Should `$("#img8>img").prop('src','objy.image_medium'); ` be changed to `$("#img8>img").prop('src', objy.image_medium); `? You are surrounding the `objy.image_medium` in quotes, so that leads me to believe the actual HTML is ending up looking something like `<img src="objy.image_medium" />`, which is probably not the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$.parseJSON(html)` on live and check. It should work.

```
success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {      
    if(html.status){        
        $("#img8>img").prop('src','html.image_medium');     
    }else{
        alert(html.error);
    }
},
```

Comment: the result is still same

Comment: Try console logging html like success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {  console.log(html) }. What reponse do you get?

Comment: the image still not appear

Comment: i just think that the problem is in json_encode because it is work properly in localhost but not in my web

Comment: Paste in your json response